# How do I make the spacing between each section the same?

Tags: spacing

I'm using the LaTeX [resume template](https://www.overleaf.com/project/652f6bdb2459bed8dbca3d2f) provided on the r/EngineeringResumes wiki, and in it they manually add `\vspace`s of different lengths to make the spacing between the sections the same.

This is not ideal, because every time I change the number of lines in a section, I'll have to set the vspace lengths again.

I found [Same vertical spacing above and below section, subsection and chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450257/same-vertical-spacing-above-and-below-section-subsection-and-chapter), and tried using the answer's `\titlespacing*{\section}` (because I'm not using KOMA-Script).

My code is:

```latex
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Using Shottr to measure the pixel distances, I've found that the spacing is still inconsistent.
[image: screenshot of inconsistent spacing]

I've uploaded the [full source code of my MWE to Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/40aJL8qj).

What's going wrong here?

### Edit #1

Thank you Werner for the comment. Using `nosep`, I have:

```latex
\newcommand{\BeginBulletList}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=12pt]}
```

This helps, but doesn't completely solve the problem. Now, the lengths are 61px and 57px.

I think ideally, I'd like code that affects the *sections* rather than specific elements within each section, so that I wouldn't need to patch new elements whenever I add them. Is that possible?

Comment: Look at that! The difference seems to be around using a list. If you're using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), you can use the `nosep` option to remove the addition of any vertical separation.

Comment: Thank you @Werner for the tip. Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the issue for me. I've edited my post with more information.

Comment: Please add your example here instead of in a pastebin. Looking at it, it seems that you use a lot of `\vspace` here and there. I guess that leaves you on your own. I suggest that you try to set up the environments so that you do not need that manual spacing.

Comment: @mickep The example is rather long, and there doesn't seem to be a way to collapse it, so I decided to upload it elsewhere instead of making the question super long. What do you suggest reading to learn how to set up the environments?

Comment: I know of no such manual, but I've learned that manually adding skips here and there is a good recipe for failure. I'd start out without the vskips and then look at the manuals of the package for changing sections and for making of itemizations. Likely they have some setups for vertical spacing one can use.